# How to achieve optimal inheritance-like with C struct?

Tags: arrays, c, inheritance, struct

I come from an OOP background and have struggle with what is the optimal (speed wise) way of implementing what I need.

I define the below struct:

```
struct Vehicle {
    int A;
    int B;
}
```

And I want some other struct like:

```
// is Vehicle
struct Bike {
    int C;
}
// is Vehicle
struct Car {
    int D;
}
```

In the end I have a function:

```
void f(struct Vehicle vehicles[], int nVehicles) {
    for(int i=0;i<nVehicles;++i){
        struct Vehicle v = vehicles[i];
        //if v is a car do something
        //else if a bike do something else
    }
}
```

that takes an array of `Vehicle` as parameter and these can be either `bike` either `car`.

In `f` I need to access `A`,`B` and `C` if a `bike` or `D` if a car.
How do I implement this?

For now I have done the below which works but I think is very inefficient and bad:

```
struct Bike {
    int A;
    int B;
    int C;
}

struct Car {
    int A;
    int B;
    int D;
}

struct Vehicle {
    char* vehicleType;
    struct Bike;
    struct Car;
}
void f(struct Vehicle vehicles[], int nVehicles) {
    for(int i=0;i<nVehicles;++i){
        struct Vehicle v = vehicles[i];
        char *vehicleType = v.vechicleType
        if(strcmp(vehicleType, "Bike")==0) {
            // Do something
        } else if(strcmp(vehicleType, "Car")==0) {
            // Do something else
        }
    }
}
```

I should note that I define the struct once and never modify their attributes, I am only reading them.

Comment: A `union` with the type specified by an `enum` is a typical solution.

Comment: struct typedefs are 100% OK. Pointer typedefs are not. Do not trust everything you read in 12y old posts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's mostly been said in the comments, but here's a workup of what's been said (and I have not used any `typedef`s, but personally I would).

So, point 1, use an `enum` for your `vehicleType`, and point 2, a `vehicle` can't be both a `Car` and a `Bike` so this is a good place to use a `union` to save space.

All of which leads us to something like this:

```
enum VEHICLE_TYPE { bike, car };

struct Vehicle
{
    enum VEHICLE_TYPE vehicleType;
    union u 
    {
        struct Bike
        {
            int top_speed;
        } Bike;

        struct Car
        {
            int number_of_seats;
        } Car;
    } u;
} Vehicle;
```

And you might then do:

```
int main ()
{
    struct Vehicle v;
    v.vehicleType = bike;
    v.u.Bike.top_speed = 100;
    ...
}
```

Most people (including myself!) would probably disagree with how I've (mis-) used upper and lower case here.  Sorry, bit rushed.

Answer (score 0):

I would use C-style cast to pointer:

```
struct Bike {
    int A;
    int B;
    int C;
};

struct Car {
    int A;
    int B;
    int D;
};

struct Vehicle {
    const char* vehicleType;
};

void f(struct Vehicle vehicles[], int nVehicles) {
    for (int i = 0; i < nVehicles; ++i) {
        Vehicle v = vehicles[i];
        const char* vehicleType = v.vehicleType;
            if (strcmp(vehicleType, "Bike") == 0) {
                Bike* b = (Bike*)&v;
                //Do what you need with 'Bike' now
                b->A = 1; //For example
                b->B = 1; //For example
                b->C = 1; //For example
            }
            else if (strcmp(vehicleType, "Car") == 0) {
                Car* c = (Car*)&v;
                //Do what you need with 'Car' now
                c->D = 2; //For example
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic pattern I experience the most for C struct inheritance is the following:

```
struct Vehicle {
    int A;
    int B;
};

struct Bike {
    struct Vehicle;
    int C;
};

struct Car {
    struct Vehicle;
    int D;
};
```

Whenever `Vehicle` is changed, sub classes automatically get these changes.

For the introspection part, the most common is a specific field, as pointed out by others and as implemented in Objective-C for instance. The idea is to define that field in the top class of the hierarchy:

```
struct Object{
    int whatami;
};
struct Vehicle {
    struct Object;
    int A;
    int B;
};
```

---

Some related questions on Software Engineering Stackexchange might be of interest:

- [What are the typical naming conventions for OO C public and private functions?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/115465/1033)
- [OO best practices for C programs](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/118253/1033)